# Nested breakout select menu with options hidden until optgroup is hovered over? React/MUI

Tags: css, reactjs, forms, select, material-ui

We use React and MaterialUI and I'm not super familiar with either at this point. What would be the best way to build a nested select menu with the following specifications:

If the options are in an optgroup, then the options are hidden until the user hovers overs then optgroup text or the child options. When hovering over the optgroup text, the options will appear directly to the right or left (depending on if there is space on the screen to the right) of the optgroup.

```
Select
------
Option1
Group1    >
Group2    >  Option 4
             Option 5
```

Assuming Group2 is selected, that's how the menu would look. And assume options 2 and 3 are behind group 1. Does that make sense?

I'm wondering if there is already something pre-built like this either in React or MUI (or otherwise but would love to not add new dependencies), or do I need to build this from scratch with onMouseOver, onMouseOut, figuring out the positioning..? Is it possible to even use the HTML select box or do I need to build something that looks and acts like a select? I've searched for pre-built options but couldn't find anything that fits, but it seems like it would be a fairly standard type of select box...

Thanks in advance.